# How to reproduce an MS Access Transform with SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot, transform

After several days of research and testing, I have to ask you the question :-)

I am trying to reproduce an MS Access query but it is not possible to use the `transform` function with SQLite

My Access request :

```sql
TRANSFORM First([A].TempMax) AS temperatures
SELECT [%$##@_Alias].moisjour
FROM (SELECT DTE, TempMax, Format(Month([DTE]),"00",2) & "-" & Format(Day([DTE]),"00",2) AS moisjour FROM meteoInfo ORDER BY DTE)  AS [A]
GROUP BY [A].moisjour
PIVOT Format([DTE],"yyyy");
```

I have a table that contains weather information for each day. Date, max temperature, min temperature. etc...

I don't need all the fields but just a few.

In my table:

```
DTE          TempMax
2022-01-01    -2, 3
2022-01-02    -7.6
...
2022-12-31    -12.7
2023-01-01    -5.9
2023-01-02    -9.2
...
2023-12-31    -15.6
2024-01-01    -2.5
2024-01-02    -4.2
2024-01-03    -6.7
...
etc.
```

I want to obtain :

```
DTE     2022   2023    2024
01-01   -2.3   -5.9    -2.5
01-02   -7.6   -9.2    -4.2
...     ....    ....   ....
31-12   ....    ....   ....
```

An answer would be welcome before I lose all my hair :-)

thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, Access's `TRANSFORM` is a pivot query that transforms data in long format to wide format. In general, conditional aggregation will work in any SQL compliant database where Access' special `TRANSFORM` query avoids writing out each conditional column.

But since your query simply pivots on year, writing out each column is not too tedious. However, since SQLite does not support the `FIRST` aggregate, you may need a `ROW_NUMBER` window function in a CTE. (Unfortunately, Access has *yet* to support these two methods).

```sql
WITH sub AS (
    SELECT 
        DTE,
        strftime('%Y', DTE) AS [Year], 
        strftime('%m-%d', DTE) AS MonDay,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', DTE)
            ORDER BY DTE
        ) AS rn
    FROM meteoInfo
)
SELECT 
    MonDay,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = '2022' AND rn = 1 THEN TempMax END) AS [2022],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = '2023' AND rn = 1 THEN TempMax END) AS [2023],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = '2024' AND rn = 1 THEN TempMax END) AS [2024]
FROM sub
GROUP BY 
    MonDay
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can we automate the year. This means that I have to modify the code every year.

Comment: Again, that is the difference of conditional aggregation vs the pivot handlers in other DBMS such as Access' `TRANSFORM`. You have to explicitly define every column. Consider going out 5, 10, 15+ years which where such columns will retain empty information until data catches up. Or use scripting languages to build SQL dynamically.